# Is there a way to identify Azure ML vs Local PC environment using Python VS Code or JupyterLab?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-machine-learning-service

I am new to Azure ML and VS Code. I'm running some projects in Azure ML, but at times I have to test it on my local PC. I was wondering if there's a way to distinguish between the two automatically so that I can load the data from the appropriate location depending on the environment. I couldn't find anything on the web search, or I couldn't understand some that I found.

Comment: if you have data in different folders then simply check if folder exists.

Comment: on local computer  you can always create `folder` or `file` or `environment variable` which doesn't exits on `Azure ML` and you can use it to detect if you run on local computer or not.